# My question banned is still active after months?

Tags: discussion

I have tried to fix and make my low quality questions better to no avail, if I do anymore the questions I get more down votes. Can I do stuff like answer questions with in my ability and edit grammar mistakes to gain the privilege back?

Comment: If https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/313938/4512 is your idea of editing to try to get your priviledges back, then you need to re-think your strategy.  You're only collecting more downvotes and digging a deeper hole.  The fundamental problem is that you seem to believe nonsense physics.  No amount of lipstick on that pig is going to help.  Go learn some *real* physics before trying here again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the canonical post on the subject [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) the answer is that possibly you can, the relevant parts are:

> The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways.
>
> If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again. But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure.

Something you might not be aware of is that while the question block won't expire automatically:

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask one new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

Just to add a few personal comments and observations:

- I've never seen it confirmed that suggested edits will help lift a ban, although they might because it is a form of positive contribution. But if you do that the edits will get reviewed by others so make sure you fix all problems and don't introduce any new ones otherwise they'll get rejected which might make things worse.
- While Stack Exchange don't confirm it officially the question ban does seem to related to answers to me. A few times I've seen users on Stack Overflow that have a bunch of heavily downvoted questions that still seem able to post new (often bad) questions because they have posted lots of good answers. Although the few I've seen have something like 50+ answers so that might not be an easy path to follow.
- Another problem you're likely to have with answers is that you don't seem to have a lot of experience / knowledge in the field and often simple questions are answered within minutes and posting new answers that don't really add much isn't normally well received. For those question what you'd really have to do is find some with mediocre answers and spend some time writing an outstanding answer.

But looking at some of the questions you've posted around the network most of the problematic ones seems to revolve around physics which you seem to have an interest in. I'd recommend getting maybe a high school level physics book and having a red hot go at reading it all and doing all the exercises, your question would be received much better if you showed a bit of basic understanding / research and you'd probably be able to work out for yourself why some ideas wouldn't work.