# How can I help? Novice in Electrical

Tags: support, editing, reputation, homework, promotion

I am learning so much here, but have a ways to go. What are ways that a low rep novice user like myself be of assistance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- You are not a novice user. You have been around for nearly two years. On every StackExchange site on which you've posted questions, you have been told patiently how to improve them, and how to contribute more meaningfully. You simply have not listened to any of the feedback you've been given.
- Earning reputation should not be the end-goal of being on these sites. Earning points and badges comes from either (a) providing great answers by being an expert in your field, or (b) asking questions that are not utter nonsense.
- If you'd like to be "of assistance," then **take a break** from visiting these sites, and instead learn the actual fundamentals of the subjects to which you want to contribute. Once you've grasped the fundamentals, then by all means come back and contribute meaningfully to the site.  I'm saying this out of a genuine concern for your learning:  trying to learn something by asking random jumbles of words is like throwing darts while blindfolded -- you will gain nothing, and will also waste time that could have been spent on proper learning.

Comment: While the two first points are good information, I think your third point is the most important. OP seems to actually _want_ to be able to ask questions here, indicating some sort of eagerness to learn. Maybe the youtube-kids of today doesn't understand that you need to sit down and learn the basics first.

Answer (score 5):

This is getting ridiculous.

You have clearly learned nothing from your previous questions here.  Attempting to answer this question would be pointless, and just repeating what was previously said anyway.

Go read the previous answers:

[Low quality question tag?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6331/4512)
[My question banned is still active after months?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6414/4512)
[Why is this question still gettng downvoted?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6416/4512)

Or better yet, just go away altogether.